# Xcode IPA Issue

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, xcode4

I having an issue with the generated ipa file.

When I generate the ipa file for ad hoc distribution everything runs smoothly on xcode, but when someone tries to download it, the app returns the error message "The application could not be installed at this time".

I tried to generate another ad hoc provisioning profile but it returns the same error.

Since I have modified nothing in my certificates could this be a xcode issue (my provisioning profile in xcode organizer are just fine)?

By the way, I noticed that after this error started to happen my IPA file has 1MB filesize and it had 1.3MB  before this error started to show up.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which type of developer account have you purchased?

Comment: Did you add the device id to the provisioning profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this issue before. You need to go into your project select your target and under **build settings** select the appropriate certificates that you added the users devices too in the provisioning profile. These will be listed under **Code Signing**

You probably have it set to automatically detect which sometimes it doesn't always detect the correct cert.

Also make sure the certificates are active on the users phones. Have them go to

Settings -> General -> Profiles ->  and make sure there is a green verified check mark next to it.

Comment: np, be sure and mark it as the answer so others having this issue know what to try to resolve it.